# Why is argparse with python 3.8 failing for me with flags with same prefix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

This question gets obsolete with the next freeipa release as @abbra mentioned.

Can someone give me a hint why I get the following error?

```
An unexpected error occurred:
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --ipa--h/--host_name/--host: conflicting option strings: --host_name, --host
```

Code:

```
@zope.interface.implementer(certbot.interfaces.IAuthenticator)
@zope.interface.provider(certbot.interfaces.IPluginFactory)
class Authenticator(certbot.plugins.dns_common.DNSAuthenticator):
    """ FreeIPA / Red Hat Enterprise Linux IdM authentication using DNS challenges """

    description = __doc__.strip().split("\n", 1)[0]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Maps provided domains to IPA zones
        self.zone_map = {}
        super(Authenticator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    @classmethod
    def add_parser_arguments(cls, add, default_propagation_seconds=10):
        super(Authenticator, cls).add_parser_arguments(add, default_propagation_seconds)
        add('-h', '--host_name', '--host', dest='ipa_host', help='Hostname or IP Address of the IPA (Satellite) server')
        add('-d', '--ipa_domain_name', '--ipa_domain', dest='ipa_domain', help='Domain in IPA (Satellite) to register under')
        add('-H', '--xml_rpc_url', '--xmlrpc-url', dest='ipa_xml_rpc_url', help='XML RPC service location')
        add('-C', '--ca_path', '--capath', dest='ca_path', help='Path do a directory containing PEM encoded CA files')
        add('-c', '--ca_file', '--cafile', dest='ca_file', help='Path do a file containing PEM encoded CA certificates')
        add('-t', '--keytab_name', '--keytab-name', dest='keytab_file', help='Path to a keytab file containing credentials for IPA server authentication')
        add('-k', '--submitter_principal', '--submitter-principal', dest='submitter_principal', help='Kerberos principal for IPA server authentication')
        add('-K', '--use_ccache_creds', '--use-ccache-creds', dest='use_ccache_creds', default=False, action='store_true', help='Use default ccache for authorization instead of authenticating')
        add('-P', '--request_principal', '--principal-of-request', dest='request_principal', help='Principal(s) (FQDN) used in signing request, comma separated')
        add('-T', '--request_profile', '--profile', dest='request_profile', help='Use a specific profile when requesting enrollment')
```

The complete code is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/antevens/cerlet). I'm trying to port this to python 3.8 as this is the recent fedora 32 python version.

Thanks in advance and please be kind. I'm an absolute Python newbie.

Comment: I removed your title formatting - that's a good way to accrue down votes here. The question is good but did you test this on a previous version and now it fails? If so, add that to your question.

Comment: I think `-h` can't be used, as it is reserved for standard help option. Try renaming `-h` to e.g. `-hn`. At least I had issues with using `-h` in my code a week ago.

Comment: @kabanus I got this code from https://github.com/antevens/cerlet it is known to be work in progress and is written for python 3.6. I have no clue if it worked under python 3.6. I'm running with 3.8.

Comment: You can disable the default meaning of `-h` by using `add_help=False` when creating the parser. This would be necessary in *any* version of `argparse`.

Comment: Where is `--ipa--h` coming from? Is the super class (`Authenticator`) adding its own arguments that conflict with yours?

Comment: The reason of error can in fact be due to super class adding same arguments.

Comment: The error here is caused by allowing the same flags on two different parser arguments - this is hidden in the `Authenticator` or `add` code you did not post.

Comment: @kabanus @adrian-w signature and constructor of Authenticator class added. I'm not sure where the parser is instantiated and how to set `allow_abbrev=False`.

Comment: FYI, @Ulrich-LorenzSchlüter, next FreeIPA major release will add native ACME support that works with pristine certbot or mod_rd. The code is (almost) in git master and it needs newer Dogtag (10.10, alpha released).

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your instance of `ArgumentParser` with `allow_abbrev=False`.

Explanation: `--host` is an abbreviation of `--host-name`. By default, abbreviations are allowed. So, `--host` is already covered by `--host-name`.

Alternatively, just leave out `--host`, as it will be matched by `--host-name` anyway.

See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#allow-abbrev